# monitor incoming http requests to a website with a loadbalancer

Tags: performance, http, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am stuck with the problem of monitoring http requests of a website with an internet-facing loadbalancer. To be specific, I have hosted a website that uses a server farm of AWS EC2 instances with a loadbalancer (ELB) at the front. Now I want to get an idea about the request arrival rate per second (or per minute) to scale the server farm.

I have thought of an approach to perform this task online. The idea is to get the ELB log each minute and parsing it for http request count for the last minute. Just wondering whether there is any efficient way to do it online.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Analyzing logs is a good way or you can use wireshark tool to monitor http traffic on ELB. Drawback is overhead on ELB but it is very less.

Comment: Where do I have to install wireshark? Can it monitor the requests from any machine given the URL of the web application?

Comment: You need to install it on load balancer (ELB). You can monitor all requests coming to ELB. It has lot many filters based on url,ip,protocol etc. It can provide the log file from which you can extract count of requests coming to ELB in a time frame and thus can find out arrival rate. sample details are http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/

Comment: @NachiketKate it's not clear what you're thinking of, but it isn't Amazon ELB.  ELB is a managed service that provides an automatically-scaling cluster of nodes to which you do not have any kind of administrative access.  You can't install anything "on" an ELB.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use AWS's cloudwatch to do the monitoring for you:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_MonitoringLoadBalancerWithCW.html

> Elastic Load Balancing publishes data points to Amazon CloudWatch
>   about your load balancers and your back-end application instances.
>   CloudWatch allows you to retrieve statistics about those data points
>   as an ordered set of time-series data, known as metrics. Think of a
>   metric as a variable to monitor, and the data points represent the
>   values of that variable over time. Each data point has an associated
>   time stamp and (optionally) a unit of measurement. For example, total
>   number of healthy EC2 instances behind a load balancer over a
>   specified time period can be a metric.
>
> Amazon CloudWatch provides statistics based on the metric data points
>   published by Elastic Load Balancing. Statistics are metric data
>   aggregations over specified periods of time. The following statistics
>   are available: Minimum (min), Maximum (max), Sum, Average, and Count.
>   When you request statistics, the returned data stream is identified by
>   the metric name and a dimension. A dimension is a name/value pair that
>   helps you to uniquely identify a metric. For example, you can request
>   statistics of all the healthy EC2 instances behind a load balancer
>   launched in a specific Availability Zone.

Comment: I have been working with AWS CloudWatch for long. However, CloudWatch doesn't provide the arrival rate of requests. The RequestCount metric of ELB is a measure of completed request count per minute, not the arrival rate.